# Searching for semantic relatedness tool

Tags: semantics, information-retrieval

I need a tool that compute the semantic relatedness between two words.Please, Have you an idea  about a tool or a code source which adopts this process. I am trying wordnet similarity (http://maraca.d.umn.edu/cgi-bin/similarity/similarity.cgi), but there is several missing words, i need one richer in term of concept.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is more like a research project. :-)

If they are just words, not phrases, the most recent technology is word embedding.  You can think of it as converting words to high-dimensional vectors (from 200 to 1000 dimensions) by training on millions of documents.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec

The code has been archived for proprietary issues but you can still download and run for yourself. Good luck.